# Dimensional regularization - integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, regularization

How can I derive the following formula?
$$\int d^{d+1} k  \frac{e^{i K X}}{K^2} = \frac{\Gamma (d-1)}{(4\pi)^{d/2} \Gamma (d/2) |X|^{d-1}}, \quad K^2 = k_0^2 + \vec k^2, KX = k_0 \tau + \vec k \vec x$$
What I tried so far:

1. Integrate over $k_0$ while promoting $k_0$ to complex variable, so I can use residue theorem. Then I move to [n-spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). I obtain:
   $$ \propto {\rm sign} (\tau) \int d \Omega \int dr \, r^{d-3} e^{-r |\tau| + ir |\vec x| \cos \phi_1}$$
   And I'm stuck.
2. I change variables to n-spherical ones and I end up with this:
   $$\int d \Omega \int dr \; r^{d-2} e^{ir |\vec x| \cos \phi_1}$$
   And I'm stuck as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R^{d+1}}}\! \frac{d^{d+1}r}{{\rm Vol}(S^{d-1})} \frac{e^{ik\cdot r}}{r^2}
~=~\int_{0}^{\infty}\!  dr~r^{d}\int_{0}^{\pi}\!d\theta~ \sin^{d-1}\theta \frac{e^{ikr\cos\theta}}{r^2}$$
$$~=~\int_{0}^{\infty}\!  dy~y^{d-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!dx~ \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^2+y^2}
~=~\int_{0}^{\infty}\!  dy~y^{d-1}~ \frac{\pi e^{-k|y|}}{y}~=~\frac{\pi\Gamma(d-1)}{k^{d-1}}, $$

where $x=r\cos\theta$, where $y=r\sin\theta$, and where

$${\rm Vol}(S^{d-1})~=~2\frac{\pi^{\frac{d}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}.$$

Answer (score -1):

The second route should work, look up the form of $d \Omega$ and note that it has a $d \cos \phi$ term that appears in it. From there, a quick change of variables and some research on gamma functions and solid angle integrals and you should be home free.

Comment: Actually $d \Omega$ contains $\sin^{d-2} \phi_1 \, d \phi_1 \ldots$

Comment: Yeah, it's a bunch of $\sin \phi$ terms followed by what is basically a $d \cos \phi$. The other $\sin$ functions give you all the gamma messiness.